# Bug using TransparentKey and resizing form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, transparent

### Steps to reproduce this bug:

- Visual Studio 2012, .net 4.0, Winforms;
- Set Background and TransparenceKey to LimeGreen;
- Set TopMost as True;

Run the application, start resizing the form to lower sizes, notice that lower than 200 px you won't be able to click in the form frame anymore (title frame and sides).

:(

[image]

### Colors

This only happens with "Click-Through" colors such as:

```
            Black
            DarkGray
            DarkGreen
            DarkMagenta
            DimGray
            ForestGreen
            Fuchsia
            Gainsboro
            Gray
            Green
            Honeydew
            LightGray
            LightGreen
            Lime
            LimeGreen
            Magenta
            PaleGreen
            Plum
            Purple
            Silver
            Thistle
            Violet
            White
            WhiteSmoke
```

### Possible way-out

Dealing with Windows messages may be the last resort... but why this happens?

```
    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int cGrip = 20;
    private const int cCaption = 35;
    private const int cBorder = 7;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (stage == 0 || stage == 4)
        {
            if (m.Msg == (int)WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                #region Hit Test
                // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
                Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
                pos = this.PointToClient(pos);

                //Bottom Left
                if (pos.X <= cGrip && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                    return;
                }

                //Bottom Right
                else if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip &&
                    pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                    return;
                }

                //Top Left
                else if (pos.Y <= cBorder && pos.X <= cBorder)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTTOPLEFT;
                    return;
                }

                //Top Right
                else if (pos.Y <= cBorder && pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cBorder)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTTOPRIGHT;
                    return;
                }

                //Top
                else if (pos.Y <= cBorder)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTTOP;
                    return;
                }

                //Caption
                else if (pos.Y < cCaption && pos.X > 50 && pos.Y < ClientSize.Width)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTCAPTION;
                    return;
                }

                //Bottom
                else if (pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cBorder)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTBOTTOM;
                    return;
                }

                //Left
                else if (pos.X <= cBorder)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTLEFT;
                    return;
                }

                //Right
                else if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cBorder)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HitTest.HTRIGHT;
                    return;
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: You actually have .NET 4.5.  I'm seeing some flakiness, not quite what you describe.  I think it is a DWM bug in Windows 8.  Its emulation of layered windows has always been kinda flaky.  Just wait for the update :)

Comment: Yes, I have W8.1 with .net 4.5.1 but my Project is .Net4.0... So this won't happen with Windows 7? (XP or Vista) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick way out:

After a month, I finally discovered something that Works (but it is something bad at the moment, since my program needs the less flickering of the form as possible)

Just make a ResizeBegin and ResizeEnd and change the color of transparency key and the backcolor of the form.

```
    private void Legacy_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //By changing the this properties, the form, somehow, don't loose the hittest..
        panelTransparent.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    }

    private void Legacy_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelTransparent.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
    }
```